# How to get the list of types in an assembly which has unresolved dependencies?

Tags: .net, dependencies, assemblies

I want to list down all the types mentioned in a DLL(assembly) which has some dependencies to other DLLs that I don't have access to.

Is there a way to dismiss those dependencies and just get the name of the available types and classes?

Using Assembly.Load("assembly full name") function I can load the assembly, but when I try to get the types using Assembly.GetTypes() I get the following error:

"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

BTW, I'm doing this all in silverlight, though I get this error both in .net and silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full .NET client you would need to load the assembly in a reflection only context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k.aspx

It does not look like this method is in Silverlight itself though.